# Custom domain DNS using NGINX

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, vps

it's my first time setting up a linux environment. I've been using cpanel for my php apps but recently i wanted to try new tech i.e nodejs so i bought a vps.

I was able to setup nginx but im now having problem on how I can route my domain from other provider to my vps.

If i bought a domain from other domain provider, with cpanel i just update the nameservers but with this setup i'm not really sure how to proceed.

Here's what dns looks like on my current domain provider.

```
 DNS:
 ns1.pananames.com
 ns2.pananames.com
 ns3.pananames.com
 ns4.pananames.com
```

here's what my `sites-available/vain.pw` looks like:

```
 server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        root /var/www/vain.pw/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx.debian.html index.php;
        server_name vain.pw www.vain.pw;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
      }
 }
```

What should I put on my provider's DNS records for it to route to my vps? Am I missing a setup on my NGINX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the registrar of your domain `vain.pw` you point them to the nameservers that host the zone for `vain.pw`. Often, registrars will have their own simple DNS server that you can use for free. Or you can use something like AWS Route 53 (and in that case, you'd point your registrar's NS records to AWS's name servers that you're provided when you buy the DNS service).

Nevertheless, whoever hosts your zone will then need to have A records made to point to the hosts that you choose. In your case, whatever the public IP address is for your nginx server.

P.S. Ditch cPanel and git gud plz. 2019-you will thank 2018-you.

Comment: That worked. Yeah, I really need to git gud. Thank you!

Comment: @kamaelxiii And git gud you shall. The day after you bug out, shell up, and burn down cPanel. =)